# pandas: exponentially weighted *rolling* correlation?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas provides various metrics for

- a rolling window, including observations `[t-window, t]`
- an `ewm` window, including observations `[0, t]`, with exponential weights

Is there any way to combine the two, that is to get exponentially weighted metrics for values only in `[t-window, t]`?

Eg. for `data = [1,2,3,4,5]`, the `mean()` of a rolling window of size 3 at position 5 would be `mean([3,4,5])`, while for an `ewm` window, it would be a weighted mean, with weights and values

```
(1-a)**4, 1
(1-a)**3, 2
(1-a)**2, 3
(1-a)**1, 4
(1-a)**0, 5
```

where `a` is the smoothing factor. Would it be possible to set a `window=3` size to the second case, taking only the last 3 weights & values into account?

Comment: Can you provide sample data an expected ouput?

Comment: @ScottBoston: edited